# Key in HashMap java

Tags: java, hashmap

I usually come across scenarios while using HashMap in Java as follows :
I've a list of Objects of class A (`List<A>`) 
A has fields int f1, int f2 and other fields.

I've to construct a map from List to perform O(1) lookup for the Objects of A. The key is combination of f1 and f2 (both being integers).

Now which of the following would be the best practice to use for the map 
case 1 : in general
case 2 : f2 can take only 2 to 3 different values, while f1 can take large number of values.

```
Map<Integer, Map<Integer, List<A>>>  // construction of map is cumbersome
Map<String, List<A>>                 //(key : String f1 + "_" + f2)
Map<Integer, List<A>>          //(I tend to use this for case 2)
```

Missed to clarify one thing here. f1 and f2 don't uniquely identify objects of A. Corrected the map definitions.

Comment: All three are good options. Which one to use depends on your specific situation.

Answer (score 0):

If those two fields tend to be immutable (they don't change once set), you can override the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods of A, and simply store a:

```
Set<A>    //(key: fields f1 and f2, via hashCode() method)
```

If they are not immutable, you cannot use them for the key anyway, since they might change.

Answer (score 0):

I think Map is suitable for case 1, and for case, i recommend List, and this list only have 2-3 elements, then you can map an index to the specific field value.

Answer (score 0):

Why use a map at all? If you don't really need Key-Value pairs, you can just use a `HashSet<A>`. The lookup is still O(1) and you don't have to bother getting a value from the key.

Of course, the HashSet is probably just a HashMap with null values, but you don't have to invent keys and values.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like using Strings as composite keys. Some blogger out there put it well: Strings are good for things that are text, and not good for things that aren't text.

Why not just create a simple `IntPair` class with two `int` fields, and appropriate `hashCode()` and `equals(Object)` overrides? It'll take you two seconds in an IDE (not much longer without one), and you'll have a more specific, semantically meaningful key type.

Answer (score -1):

Key is unique in HashMap...because internally in java key is set as

```
final Key
```

int static Entry class in java

That's why the key is unique it won't allow duplicates...